# Answer to followup questions also answers original question

Tags: discussion

Regarding these two questions:

1. [Different Font for different Languages (mixed in glossaries)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383784)
2. [Glossaries and \libertineGlyph and \makebox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383918)

I answered the second question which turned out to be a followup on the first question which hadn't been solved. My answer to the second question also answers the first, but they're not duplicates. There seem to be several possible options:

1. Edit my answer on the second question, moving the bulk of it to answer the first question, leaving just the bit that directly answers the question. (Will this cause confusion, especially since the comments are directed towards the first part?)
2. Move the entire answer (and comments) from the second question to the first and trim off the small part that answers the second question. (Needs a mod?)
3. Answer the first question with a brief summary. (Future visitors wanting to know the details would need to go over to the original answer, which would be a nuisance.)

The first question is more likely to be of general use to future visitors, so I don't think it should be closed.

What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: The following is an interesting, related read about duplicates/closures: [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/168244) Primarily, duplicate (or the same) answer is sometimes an indication that the questions are the same (or duplicate).

Comment: @Werner The answer to the second question is basically "don't use special characters in the label of glossary entries". The answer to the first question details how to have a glossary with the name in one script/language (Hebrew) and the description in another (German). So I don't think the questions are really the same in this case. It's just that the original code fragment supplied in the second question had a glossary entry definition with Hebrew in the name and German in the description. If it had all been in a Latin script they'd be no link between them (except the use of `glossaries`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I decided that the best solution was to split my original answer so that the main bulk of it now answers [Different Font for different Languages (mixed in glossaries)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383784). This question title is more relevant to the answer than the other question and is more likely to be found through searches, so I think that's more generally useful to future visitors.

I've trimmed down my answer to [Glossaries and \libertineGlyph and \makebox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383918) so that it's now a follow-up to the previous answer.